# Redirecting www url to non www url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I am able to redirect the `base url` of my website from `www to non www` in `nginx configuration` but the problem is I am sending email in which the url is with the www.

```
www.xyz.com -> xyz.com
```

successfully redirects but when I try to run the url like

```
www.xyz.com/pqr
```

it did not get redirected.

I am using `rails 5.0.7 and ruby 2.5.1`

Comment: Why don't you change the configuration of your mailer and send URLs without `www`?

Comment: @spickermann clients may have already received emails with wrong urls

Answer (score 0):

There must be some issues in your nginx redirection config, try:

```
server {
  server_name  www.example.com;
  rewrite ^(.*) https://example.com$1 permanent;
}
```

key is in keeping the path part of the url in `$1`

Comment: Thank you for your rply, There was already rewrite in my nginx confiig except `(.*)` so I added it but still it is not working.

Comment: @AshishJambhulkar what's output of `curl -v http://www.(yourdomain).com` ?

Comment: @AshishJambhulkar interesting part is how Location header changes if you add some path to url

Comment: I turned all url addersses to http and now they are redirecting properly to the non www, the problem with only https www urls.

Comment: @AshishJambhulkar then there must be separate `server` block for https vhost somewhere near that swallows them, probably main server with `server_name www.example.com example.com` or `default`/`_`